# Maximum depth exceeded react error while using useEffect()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Error: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setProducts(getCartProducts());
}, [products]);
```

When passing an empty array as the second argument, the app works fine but in order to reflect the changes on the page I have to refresh it, but after passing the 'items' object as the second argument in the array, I receive the above error.

Comment: It seems that setItems is indirectly affecting the value of products. Can you provide some more context around your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setProducts(getCartProducts());
}, [products]);
```

This is equivalent to setting state inside componentDidUpdate without any conditions.
You are updating your state inside `useEffect` that is correct but passing your same state inside `dependency array` as an argument which will be updated inside your effect is **`wrong`**. You should set change your dependency injection and you should re-evaluate your code and mark your dependency array accordingly. If you are setting `products` as your effect's dependency array then your are just saying to react that run this effect whenever **`products`** updated and inside effect you are just updating **`products`**, so it does not make any sense, one thing you can do is use an auxiliary state for running your effect.

Comment: thank you, I'll try to fix the issue using an auxiliary state as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setItems` (you meant `setProducts`, right?) in the `useEffect`, forces `products` state to be updated, which then forces `useEffect` to be called.

By passing `[products]` as a second argument you watch for the changes made on this field. And the value of `products` changes. I guess it's because `getCartProducts()` produces new reference (is non-primitive, like a object, or an array). That's why React thinks the field has changed.

That forms a loop.

Comment: yes, just as I thought so, thank you for pointing that out but could you please suggest any fix for the same?

Comment: how about: `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])`?