# How to fix this Maximum depth exceeded error with useEffect and useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have events which is pulled from redux, and if the `events` array contains data, then `updateData` will be used to filter events into the state var `data`.

I have `data` and `events` both added to the dependency array as [talked about here.](https://www.benmvp.com/blog/object-array-dependencies-react-useEffect-hook/) but I'm still getting this error:

[image]

```
const SingleTable = () => {
    const events = useSelector(state => eventsSelector(state));
    const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
    const [sortCol, updateSortCol] = useState(0);
    const [sortDir, updateSortDir] = useState('ascending');

    useEffect(() => {
        const formattedArray = events ? formatLoss(events): [];

        events && updateData(formattedArray);
    }, [data, events]);

    //...
```

Thoughts, ideas?

Comment: Cannot see your images.

Comment: you dont need to listen vor `data` in `useEffect`, you only want to update `data` when `events` changed.

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Folks block these images or cannot read them due to vision impairments -- always use text for text, not screenshots of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum depth exceeded while using useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903158/maximum-depth-exceeded-while-using-useeffect). See also [Maximum depth exceeded react error while using useEffect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410528/maximum-depth-exceeded-react-error-while-using-useeffect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are executing useEffect callback whenever data changes and you are changing data in useEffect callback.

Remove data as dependency.

Use this code to fix it

```
const SingleTable = () => {
const events = useSelector(state => eventsSelector(state));
const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
const [sortCol, updateSortCol] = useState(0);
const [sortDir, updateSortDir] = useState('ascending');

useEffect(() => {
    const formattedArray = events ? formatLoss(events): [];

    events && updateData(formattedArray);
}, [events]);

//...
```